# Group_by with summarize_each changes the original order of index column

Tags: r, sum, grouping

I am trying to group and sum a dataset based on the first column which contains economic sectors. The problem is that when I do, the original order of the entries of the first column changes to alphabetical. I need this order to be preserved for later analysis. Here is my code:

```
df <- inner_join(df2, df3, by= "sector")
df <- df%>% 
  group_by(sector) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

I also tried converting the column from characters to factors, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking data, I'll demonstrate with `mtcars`.

The data orders `cyl=6` first:

```r
head(mtcars)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

But summarizing reorders:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#     cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  293. 1156.   909  44.8  25.1  211.    10     8    45    17
# 2     6  138. 1283.   856  25.1  21.8  126.     4     3    27    24
# 3     8  211. 4943.  2929  45.2  56.0  235.     0     2    46    49
```

We can add the row number, summarize appropriately (but differently), and then reorder:

```r
mtcars %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(rn = min(rn), across(-rn, ~ sum(.))) %>%
  arrange(rn)
# # A tibble: 3 x 12
#     cyl    rn   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     6     1  138. 1283.   856  25.1  21.8  126.     4     3    27    24
# 2     4     3  293. 1156.   909  44.8  25.1  211.    10     8    45    17
# 3     8     5  211. 4943.  2929  45.2  56.0  235.     0     2    46    49
```

Comment: Hi r2evans,, i apologize for not including some data, i'm not permitted by my employer and was checking if this worked without. I am getting an error saying that it does not find the function "across".

Comment: You must have an older version of `dplyr`, that was merged almost two years ago (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/4586) into `dplyr-1.0.0`. I'm using `dplyr-1.0.5` in R-4.0.5 here.

Comment: Ah yes, thats it. I am working with 0.8.3... I will have to check whether I can update this inside my working environment. I am sure it will work , thank you!